# Can I update a preference summary when the DialogPreference is closed?

Tags: android, android-preferences, android-dialog, android-lifecycle

I would like to do this without an `onSharedPreferenceChanged` listener because one of my settings is actually stored in a database, not in a preference. My impression was that `onResume` functions are called when dialogs close, but it's not being called when I close my custom DialogPreference. I would like to do something like the following, which is in my Settings Activity, but `onResume` is not being called.

```
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Preference pref = findPreference(getString(R.string.pref_semester_id));
        pref.setSummary(Semester.getCurrentSemester(this).getSemesterString());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I called my activity's `onResume` from my dialog's `onDialogClosed` method and that seems to have done the trick.

In `onDialogClosed`...
`((settingsActivity).this.getContext()).onResume();`

Comment: This is dangerous, you shouldn't play with lifecycle methods like that.  Instead, put the code in your onResume into a function and call that in both places (onResume and onDialogClosed).